# DataContext and DesignData - File not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my current layout I want some data be visible in the design view so I read about DataContext and DesignData and I fail to use that correctly.

My MainPage.xaml starts this way:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="AppStalker.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=./SampleData/SampleData.xml}">
```

My application compiles without warnings/errors and I can see the data in the emulator. Anyway after building the solution VS 2012 complains that it can't find `C:\path\to\project\AppName\SampleData\SampleData.xml`

I triple checked that I have no typos and I also changed xml to xaml with no effect. I also triple verified that the Solution View shows the directory and the file.

Now it gets interesting: If I change the path to `Source=./App.xaml` it doesn't complain. If I change it to reference MainPage.xaml it complains about some errors in the file. If I move my `SampleData.xml` to the same root directory like `App.xaml` it still refuses to find them...

I also changed the build action of the file to `Resource`, `Embedded Resource`, `DesignData` but nothing changed.

Basically I follow this [LongListSelector Walkthrough](http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~acm/hackathon/LongListSelectorTutorial.html#Leveraging_designer)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

the file should be `Resource`

If you want to place the file in the root directory of the project; besides `App.xaml`, just write:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData.xml}"
```

and if you want to place it inside a folder in your project:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleFoodData.xml}"
```

and it's the same as:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=SampleData/SampleFoodData.xml}"
```

Comment: Changes nothing. Still complaining that the file can't be found.

Comment: I've downloaded the sourceCode from the link you have provided, and changed the dataContext code:

full sourceCode: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwZbbu48kobsbjU2T0ZMOV9Dd1E/edit?usp=sharing